# Help with one definition of "déterminer" found in an old French dictionary

Tags: sens, synonymes, ancien-français

I'm getting tripped up with the following definition for "[**déterminer**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/d%C3%A9terminer)", from Dictionnaire de l'Académie française 4th Edition (1762):

> Donner une certaine qualité, une certaine façon d'être, à ce qui de
>   soi-même n'a pas plutôt celle-là qu'une autre.

Is this meaning of "déterminer" still valid today and if so, what exactly does it mean (paraphrased, if possible, in a little more simpler way in French) and/or if not, what would be one or two common synonyms for this meaning of "déterminer"?

Answer (score 3):

**"En termes de Philosophie,"** seems key. This is (or was) a very narrow usage of the word, and as a native speaker, I hardly understand the given definition (because the philosophy is hard to decipher).

The way I understand it, it resembles "**convince**" (*convaincre*, *pousser à*, *inciter* for a living object, *rendre*, *transformer*, *faire*, for an inanimate thing). In words:

> make something be in a way that it wasn't all by itself

I don't know if french philosophers still use such a sense of the word. I don't see a reason for them to stop doing so, nor a better word to express the same thing, so I'd suppose they do.

Answer (score 3):

> [Donner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donner) une certaine qualité, une certaine façon d'être, [à](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)
>   [ce](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce) [qui](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/qui) [de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) [soi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soi)-[même](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%AAme) n'a [pas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas) [plutôt](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plut%C3%B4t)
>   [celle-là](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/celle-l%C3%A0) [qu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que)'une [autre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autre).

Pas toujours, mais souvent, *donner qqc. à qqn./qqc*. L'objet indirect est introduit par « *à* » dans ce cas. Donc ici donner qqc. *à qqc. qui* (~indépendamment) n'a pas, de préférence, une certaine qualité, une certaine façon d'être; bien, lui donner une certaine qualité, une certaine façon d'être.[!] *Celle-là* : mais laquelle donc ? Bien il n'y a pas d'opposition entre la qualité et la façon d'être; peut-être y a-t-il une alternance (comme avec *celle-ci, celle-là*, mais ici sans mentionner une des deux: *celle-là, une autre*). Usuellement on pourrait ainsi désigner à l'écrit le terme le plus éloigné du locuteur, le premier terme, la *qualité*. À l'oral ce serait ce dont on vient de parler, le dernier terme, la *façon d'être*. Mais les deux termes sont une variation sur un même thème, et il s'agit d'un propriété, ou d'une autre, similaire, qu'on n'énumère pas, que l'on veut attribuer à quelque chose. Qu'on réfère précisément à celle-ci ou à celle-là n'a pas d'impact direct sur le sens ici. On pose une étiquette, peut-être plus concrète ou subjective, sur un objet essentiellement neutre, on y détermine quelque chose :

> *La plupart des Philosophes tiennent que la matière est indifférente au
>   repos ou au mouvement, & qu'il faut que quelque chose la détermine à
>   l'un ou à l'autre.  Qu'est-ce qui détermine ce corps à se mouvoir en ligne 
>   courbe plutôt qu'en ligne droite? On dit, Déterminer un mot à un sens,
>   à une signification, pour dire, L'employer précisément dans une telle
>   signification. Ce mot est équivoque de lui-même, mais ce qui précède &
>   ce qui suit le déterminent nécessairement au sens que vous lui donnez,
>   en déterminent le sens.*
>
> [ *Dictionnaire de l'Académie*, 4e ed., exemple suivant la citation en
>   question, à « déterminer » ]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough paraphrase based on my interpretion of the definition:

> Donner/attribuer une certaine qualité ou une certaine façon d’être à quelque
>   chose qui n’a pas en soi(-même) cette qualité ou façon d’être [plus
>   que d’autres qualités ou façons d’être].

(or said otherwise to use the word « inhérent » for the notion of « en soi-même » (*in [and of] itself*)

> Donner/attribuer à quelque chose une certaine qualité ou une certaine façon d’être qui n’est pas inhérente [plus que d’autres] à cette chose.

If a synonym or two would help, working backwards from English, I arrive at the notion of « [définir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/definir) » or “[assigner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/assigner)” (as in « to [randomly] define/assign the terms/values/limits of …” in English, for the purpose of further analysis).

Comment: @Amphiteóth Thanks! That certainly makes more sense. I struggled with that & even considered making “qui n’est pas” plural to try to ‘redirect’ the relation back to the first clause, but wasn't sure if ‘compound’ subjects with “ou” (that I added) take the plural (alas, I'm clearly in way over my head here). Your ‘indépendamment’, being an adverb, has the big advantage of working without changing the word order. I was tempted to coin “inhérentement” (for some reason “fondamentalement” didn’t work for me), but I think ‘indépendamment’ (or just staying with “en soi”) works well here as an adverb.

Comment: "Et" would have been required for that I think instead of "ou"; still, unclear to me. But maybe ultimately the required adverb was a cross between indépendamment and inhérent, maybe that was [_ontologiquement_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ontologiquement). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are ok, underlining *"déterminer"* phylosophical part and usage but I want to paraphrase as you asked it.

> Donner une certaine qualité, une certaine façon d'être, à ce qui de soi-même n'a pas plutôt celle-là qu'une autre.

1. « Donner une certaine qualité » = To give a feature, a quality
2. « une certaine façon d'être, » = a special way of being
3. « à » = to [something]
4. « ce qui de soi-même » = by itself
5. « n'a pas » = doesn't have
6. « plutôt celle-là qu'une autre. » = this one (this feature in particular) more than another.

---

So It can be said as follow :

> To give a feature, a quality, a special way of being, to something which, by itself, doesn't have it more than another specific one.

This sentence is weird in french too.

Comment: The OP asked in english, the forum is called French Language and not Langage Français, so I would like to know why I was downvoted :(

Comment: @ yohann v Maybe you got downvoted because your translation is wrong on an essential point: "de soi-même " does not refer to the person reading the definition ("yourself") but indeed  to the object that is "determiné"."Give a feature ...to something which does not have it by itself"

Comment: @P.Obertelli I'm happy people corrected me and did not just press the down button ;)

Answer (score 1):

C'est une définition ancienne et qui ne se retrouve plus dans l'usage quotidien. Aujourd'hui, "déterminer", aurait plutot le sens de "trouver", "d'identifier", "définir".

Par contre,on retrouve ce sens ancien de *déterminer* dans certains mots formes sur la meme racine:

- *indéterminé*, se dit d'une qualité inconnue, mais aussi qui ne peut pas etre connue (et donc il faut la 'déterminer', la trouver, ou peut-etre la 'déterminer', en décider);
- *déterminisme*, l'idée que chaque événement est déterminé, rendu inévitable, par la causalité.
- *détermination*, l'obstination.